# Android 13 (Tiramisu) Emulator Debug App Notification can't be turn on

Tags: java, android

Any idea how to enable the permission on the app? the permission was disabled by default on Android 13 Emulator. It was working on other emulator, just not Android 13 Emulator. By default, adding Firebase Messaging will add the Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS into the Manifest.

[image]

requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);

auto return isGranted = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

This is how to request and check results for runtime for api13

```
 private void request_notification_api13_permission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 22);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 22) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0)
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

               // permission granted, perform required code

            } else {
                // not granted
            }
    }
}
```

calling function will be like this:

```
request_notification_api13_permission();
```